# How to switch behavior depending on local host or IP

Tags: r, portability

I am developing R code that needs to run redundantly on two servers.  Some aspects of the code (like file paths or error message footers) need to be specific to each server.  Rather than have server-specific versions of each file, I would prefer to switch based on the hostname or ip of the machine currently running the code.  How do I

I'm picturing something like this

```
if(localIP == 123.45.678.9){
  msg = "Sent by server A"
} else if (localIP == 123.55.555.5) {
  msg = "Sent by server B"
} else {
  msg = "Default message"
}
```

So, how do I get that localIP value or something similarly identifying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the host name is typically available as an environment variable:

```
# Windows: COMPUTERNAME, Linux: HOST or HOSTNAME
host <- Sys.getenv(c("COMPUTERNAME", "HOST", "HOSTNAME"))
host <- unname(host[nchar(host)>0][1])
```

...But perhaps it would be cleaner to add a custom environment variable when you start R:

```
R -f myscript.R myserver=A
```

Then get that env variable from your script:

```
server <- Sys.getenv("myserver")
msg <- switch (server, A="Sent by server A", B="Sent by server B", "Default message")
```

Comment: thanks!  The Sys.getenv isn't actually working for me (none of those values are set), but that opened the window to the Sys. family of functions that I was unaware of.  Also your env variable solution is very clean indeed.  I should start thinking along those lines.

Comment: @SamSwift - You can always try `names(Sys.getenv())` to see what environment variables are defined.

Answer (score 0):

Tommy gets credit for the answer, but I wanted to document the solution it led me to which is just slightly different.

Sys.info() returns a number of variables about the platform.  The nodename attribute returns "A name by which the machine is known on the network (if any)."

```
host <- Sys.info()["nodename"]
```

It should be noted that Sys.info() "is not implemented on all platforms" so this isn't entirely portable.

Comment: this also works (on linux hosts):
    system("hostname", intern=T)